# Steps to redirect Application URL to Custom URL

Tags: apache, http, url-routing, aix

i have IHS 7 installed on an AIX system and its pointing to Application Server . now my requirement is if Application is not accessible or if we are working on the Application it self then whoever access the URL, it redirects to a custom page on the webserver that Application is under construction . 
for example url is https://my.Application.com:8089/application if anyone hits this URL then this URL is redirected to custom URL on same webserver https://my.webserver

i have configured a proxy on IHS httpd.conf but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

The good practice in such case is to create two config files and one maintenance page. When your app server do not work you should restart http server with config file which point to the maintenance page.